# How to get data from activity class to the PhoneStateListener class?

Tags: android

I have a problem in which I can't get data from activity class to the PhoneStateListener class.

for better understanding the code is as below:

This is the class from where I want to send the data or string

```
package net.cellobject.blockingincomingcall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SecondTab extends Activity
{
    EditText e1;
    Button b1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.setting);

        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

        LoadPreferences();

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String msg=e1.getText().toString();

                SavePreferences("msg1",msg);

                LoadPreferences();

                if(msg=="")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First 


                                               Enter the message then save it"

                                               ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    e1.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void LoadPreferences() 
    {
        SharedPreferences shp= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        String s1=shp.getString("msg1","");

        e1.setText(s1);
    }

    private void SavePreferences(String key, String msg) 
    {
        SharedPreferences shp= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shp.edit();

        editor.putString(key, msg);

        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

This is the class where I want to get the data or string which is extends with PhoneStateListener?

```
package net.cellobject.blockingincomingcall;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;


public class PhoneCallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{   
    private Context context;    

    public PhoneCallStateListener(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {
        switch (state) 
        {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:               

                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.

                                                 getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   

                //Turn ON the mute

                audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);     



                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.

                                               getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

                    Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());

                    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                    method.setAccessible(true);

                    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);     

                    //Checking incoming call number

                    String incoming=incomingNumber.toString();

                    if (incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(incoming)) 
                    {
                        Log.v("incoming_call",incoming);

                        telephonyService.endCall();

                        sendSMS(incoming, "I am Busy!!call me later");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);

            break;
        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }

    private void sendSMS(String incoming, String string) 
    {
        android.telephony.SmsManager sms=android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();

        sms.sendTextMessage(incoming, null, string, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `Context` in both `Activity and Receiver` you may use `SharedPreference` to set and get data on both places.. WHats the problem..

```
context.getSharedPreference("name" , MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: how it works explain properly and give me a simple but complete example

Answer (score 0):

im posting a very simple method to store and get preferences, use this i will solve your problem related to store and retrieve preferences.

```
public class Preferences {


public static void record(String key,Context context,String value)
{
    SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences .Editor editor=pref.edit();

    editor.putString(key,value );
    editor.commit();


}
public static String getRecord(String key,Context context)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key,PREF_DEFAULT_VALUE);

}
```

}